# ubuntu how to bulk rename files

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, rename

I have about 1000 files with 2_0 in them that need to be 4_30

here's the BEFORE filename convention

```
 ov_5_13_2020_2_0.csv
 ov_3_24_2020_2_0.csv
```

I need the AFTER to look like this

```
 ov_5_13_2020_4_30.csv
 ov_3_24_2020_4_30.csv
```

I tried

```
$rename -n 's/\*2020_2*/\*2020_4*/' *.csv
```

but it did nothing. cli is NOT my strong suite so can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your filenames don't have any literal `*`'s in them, matching `\*` won't match anything.  Try

```
rename -n 's/2020_2_0/2020_4_30/' *.csv
```

which will print out all the renames it would actually do if you removed the `-n` option...

Comment: thanks chris I misread the man pages by a mile. Your solution worked like a charm and NOW I see it... thanks again